# Product Image Uploader to Preview Product M2.2.2

Tags: module, custom-options, custom-attributes, magento2.2.2, gallery-image

My goal is to have the same functionality as the "Image and Video" uploader to preview my products in a block I created.
[image]

[image]

As of right now, this is what my module looks like.

[image]

If you need any more information, just let me know! Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using the Github repo below. This allowed me to add images in the product tab.

[snowdog/module-product-custom-description](https://snow.dog/blog/tutorial-how-to-implement-an-admin-product-tab-in-magento-2/)